# How to enhance the operator "+" in perl

Tags: perl

Would like to enhance the operator "+" in perl so that it will be regular add operation if both operands are numbers

```
$a = 11;
$b = 12;
$x = $a + $b; #expect it to be 23
```

If one operand is a string, then convert all operands as string and treat them as concatenation.

```
$a = 11;
$b = " cars";
$x = $a + $b; #expect it to be "11 cars"
```

If this is not possible, wonder if it's possible for me to create a new operator to do it.

Comment: See [overload](http://p3rl.org/overload).

Comment: With `+`, basically, no, you cannot do that. You can alter how operators work on blessed objects using overloading, but you cannot alter how they operate on non-reference scalars. You can't create new operators in Perl, though [Sub::Infix](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Infix) allows you to fake it.

Comment: Perl is designed for its operators to be treated as monomorphic, and its data types to be treated as polymorphic (mostly).  Your desire is to reverse this.  You'll end up inventing a lot of heuristics to decide if a scalar value should be considered a string or a number.  This is one of those problems where people tend to not arrive at a consensus as to the right set of rules for every situation.

Comment: Wondering in what situation you want such behavior. If you doing arithmetics, you don;t want strings and when need string join, why want arithmetics? Could you please tell what want achieve?

Comment: Thanks guys for the ideas, the operands are just regular scalars, the perl code was just passed to my code for evaluation, so I can't do much (including overloading).  Sub::Infix looks very interesting, I am going to study it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl makes no distinction between variable types. This is pretty much in line with how shell scripts and awk scripts work. A variable might be a number in one place in your program and a string in another place. Perl hopes that you know what you're doing:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $vendor_id = "344";
my $inventory_item = "23942";

print "You want to order item ";
print $vendor_id + $inventory_item;
print "\n";
```

This will print:

```
You want to order item 24286
```

Which added my `$vendor_id` to my `$inventory_item`. What you probably wanted to do was to *concatenate* them.

```
You want to order item 34423942
```

There's no way Perl can tell if you meant a variable to be a string or number, so Perl forces you to use operators. The `+` is a numeric addition while `.` is a string concatenation. In many languages, this would be the same operator, but in Perl, we need two distinct operators. To do what you want, you would have done this:

```
print $vendor_id . $inventory_item;
```

vs.

```
print $vendor_id + $inventory_item;
```

This is why Perl has two completely different sets of boolean operators: One set for numeric comparisons and one for strings. This gives Perl great flexibility because a variable can be treated as a number in one place, then as a string in another. However, it also means you better know what your variable is suppose to represent.

In Python, Java, Swift, and in many other languages, you declare a variable as either a string or a number. Beware if you declare a variable as a string and try to add them, or declare them as some form of numeric data and try to concatenate them. In most languages, you have to *cast* variables from one form to another using either methods (like `int2sting`) or a declaration.

If you truly don't know your data, and are not sure what it represents, you can use `looks_like_number` from [Scalar::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html). This isn't a *builtin* function, but `Scalar::Util` is a standard module, and is probably already in your Perl distribution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
my $first = "11";
my $second = " of cars";

if ( looks_like_number($first) and looks_like_number($second) ) {
    say $first + $second;   # Add the two numbers together
}
else {
    say $first . $second;   # At least one is a string, so concatenate them
}
```

Now, if both `$first` and `$second` look like numbers, they'll be added. However, if one or the other doesn't look like a number, they'll be concatenated.

There are Perl modules (and I can't remember them) that will turn Perl into a *declarative* language where variables are told they're a string, integer, floating point number, etc. Most of these attempts are incomplete for many reasons. For example, you can't stop someone from using the more ambiguous built in syntax.

If you have more advanced Perl knowledge, you can create your own objects types, and use the `overload` pragma to overload the operation definition for each class type:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Object::Perl;    # Hypothetical module

my $first  = Object::Perl::String->new(11);
my $second = Object::Perl::String->new(" cars");

say $first + $second;    # Overloaded "+" to concatenate two Object::Perl::String types

$first  = Object::Perl::Int->new(11);
$second = Object::Perl::Int->new(12);

say $first + $second;   $ Overloaded "+" to add two Object::Perl::Int types
```

However, if you're going through all that trouble, you might as well learn Python.

Comment: Thanks David for the detailed answer! Wish It could be like javascript which has the desired behavior.

Comment: @codingFun: That's because JavaScript was *designed* and *written* that way. You'd have a very difficult job to get JavaScript to work the way Perl does. If anything, Perl is the more flexible. In any case, why do you want to write `+` for both addition and string concatenation? Is it just so that you don't have to remember another syntax?

Comment: @Borodin, when I write perl script, I use "+" and "." appropriately.  When I inherit perl code from someone who had experience with javascript, many times the bugs are due to the confusion of the operator "+" in perl vs in Javascript.

Comment: @codingFun: That is a ***dreadful*** reason to use operator polymorphism. You should *fix* bad code, not make it seem like it works.

Comment: @codingFun The problem with JavaScript is that if a variable isn't defined as a particular type, you don't know how it'll handle `+`. I may expect an addition, but it instead does a concatenation without reporting an error. Either, a language should have fixed data types (like in other scripting languages), or the language should avoid polymorphic and ambiguous operators (like Perl and Bash).

Comment: @Borodin, Agree.  Just curious if perl can be enhanced to be like Javascript in this regard.

Comment: @codingFun - You can create _objects_ and then do overloading with the `use overload` pragma to redefine `+` to be a concatenate operator. I _hinted_ at it in my answer. However, that's a lot of pain just to get Perl to use `+` instead of `.`.

Comment: Thanks David for the point. The overhead on using object compared to plain scalar is much higher.  Wish there is a way in perl to say, this  scalar is of type integer or string :-)

Comment: Re "Just curious if perl can be enhanced to be like Javascript in this regard", JavaScript variables cannot contain both a string and a number at the same time. As such, the definition of JS's operators cannot be applied to Perl variables.

Answer (score 0):

That makes no sense. For example, what should the following output?

```
my $x = 11;    print("$x\n");
my $y = 12;    print("$y\n");

print($x+$y, "\n");

my $m = "11";  print(0+$m, "\n");
my $n = "12";  print(0+$n, "\n");

print($m+$n, "\n");
```

Keep in mind that `$x` and `$m` are identical (they both contain a number and a string), and so are `$y` and `$n`.

```
SV = PVIV(0x16f2dd8) at 0x16fe8b0      $x
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,IOK,POK,pIOK,pPOK)
  IV = 11
  PV = 0x16f7b30 "11"\0
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 16
SV = PVIV(0x16f2e20) at 0x16fea60      $m
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,IOK,POK,pIOK,pPOK)
  IV = 11
  PV = 0x17086b0 "11"\0
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 16
SV = PVIV(0x16f2df0) at 0x16fe8f8      $y
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,IOK,POK,pIOK,pPOK)
  IV = 12
  PV = 0x171eee0 "12"\0
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 16
SV = PVIV(0x16f2e08) at 0x170eee8      $n
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,IOK,POK,pIOK,pPOK)
  IV = 12
  PV = 0x17320e0 "12"\0
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 16
```

Comment: Rubbishing the question doesn't make an answer. And the bitwise and/or/xor operators are fine with behaving differently according to the types of their operands.

Comment: @Borodin, They aren't fine. They are buggy. You often have to create numbers from the variables and pass that to the operators rather than using the operators directly.